# Barrier thread synchronisation in pairs

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I want to implement a function that blocks incoming threads until 2 threads of the same colour meet. Each thread is modelled by a unique id and colour. The function should return the id of the other thread it is matched to. I tried to use the idea for rendezvous and barrier to solve the question, which worked when there are only 2 threads at any one time, but when there are more than 2 threads, the id returned is incorrect. I am trying to solve for 1 colour first as the other 2 colors would have similar logic, but I am not sure what I need to change?

```
 int pack_thread(int colour, int id) {
if (colour == 1) {
    sem_wait(&d); map[0][count[0]] = id; count[0]++; 
    if (count[0] == 1) {
        sem_post(&d);
        sem_post(&a1); sem_wait(&a2); sem_post(&barr);
        return map[0][1];
    } else if (count[0] == 2) {
        sem_post(&d);
        sem_wait(&a1); sem_post(&a2);
        return map[0][0];
    } else {
        sem_post(&d);
        sem_wait(&barr);
        map[0][1] = id; 
        count[0] = 0;
        sem_post(&a2);sem_wait(&a1);
        return map[0][0];
    }
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use separate semaphore for each color.

Comment: yes, I am only testing for red here. Once 1 color works, I think I can figure out the the other 2 colors